# My simple react-dnd is not working - dragging an item causes the entire list to disappear

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I am trying to get this react-dnd code to work using the react-beautiful-dnd library.

I am not sure but for some reason my 2 lists disappear the moment you start to drag an item.

https://codesandbox.io/s/jvq5815nvy

```
return (
      <DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}>
        {board.lists.map((list, index) => (
          <Droppable droppableId={list.name}>
            {(provided, snapshot) => (
              <div
                ref={provided.innerRef}
                style={getListStyle(snapshot.isDraggingOver)}
              >
                {list.cards.map((card, index) => (
                  <Draggable key={card.id} draggable={card.id} index={index}>
                    {(provided, snapshot) => (
                      <div
                        ref={provided.innerRef}
                        {...provided.draggableProps}
                        {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                        style={getItemStyle(
                          snapshot.isDragging,
                          provided.draggableProps.style
                        )}
                      >
                        {card.title}
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </Draggable>
                ))}
                {provided.placeholder}
              </div>
            )}
          </Droppable>
        ))}
      </DragDropContext>
    );
```

It seems like clicking and dragging an item messes up, which I though was maybe the key value of the element but I can't see what I am doing wrong.

The devs who made the library created a sample sandbox with working code that I tried to mimick: I simply modified the example sandbox for the library

https://codesandbox.io/s/ql08j35j3q

**Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?**

Comment: I guess the problem lies in Draggable since your rendering through .map which renders all the item draggable , it would be better if you check this video once for this case https://egghead.io/lessons/react-move-items-between-columns-with-react-beautiful-dnd-using-ondragend

Comment: @Jayavel I'm not sure how that is different that this example where each item is draggable via a .map https://codesandbox.io/s/ql08j35j3q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is because of a little mistake.In the Draggable element, you set draggable = {card.id}

```
<Draggable key={card.id} draggable={card.id} index={index}>
      ...
</Draggable>
```

Actually,it should be draggableId = {card.id}.